# Access all photos of device in my iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, photo, photolibrary

I want to take all photos and videos from device Photos app and show it in my app. First of all is Apple allowing for the same or not? If yes how i can i do that, is Photoframework useful for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest to implement and easiest way to use if you just want to pick some photos from the user's phone is the `UIImagePickerController`.

However, if you really want to show the assets or the photos of a device into your app and not just to pick some assets, you will need to learn and use the **Photos Framework**. You'll know how to fetch `PHAssets` from the device and use them into your app.

There are lots of tutorials around the web, like so: http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/